# SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: ERROR: [doc=auth.user.23] unknown field 'firstname']

Tags: django, python-2.7, solr, django-haystack

I am trying to implement Autocomplete on the 'first_name' field of the 'User' model using Django-Haystack-Solr. But I am facing this "Unknown field" error.

**search_indexes.py:**

```
from haystack import indexes
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
      text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
      firstname = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='first_name')

      def get_model(self):
          return User

      def index_queryset(self, using=None):
          return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

**views.py**

```
results = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(firstname=request.POST.get("search_text",''))
```

I performed the following:

1. Ran the command: $ python manage.py build_solr_schema
2. Saved new schema to schema.xml
3. Ran the command: $ python manage.py rebuild_index    ---> Throws the Error

**Error:**

```
 Indexing 5 users 
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/fields.py:137: RemovedInDjango110Warning: render() must be called with a dict, not a Context.
 return t.render(Context({'object': obj}))

 Failed to add documents to Solr: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: ERROR: [doc=auth.user.23] unknown field 'firstname']
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py", line 72, in update
     self.conn.add(docs, commit=commit, boost=index.get_field_weights())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysolr.py", line 860, in add
     return self._update(m, commit=commit, softCommit=softCommit, waitFlush=waitFlush, waitSearcher=waitSearcher)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysolr.py", line 462, in _update
     return self._send_request('post', path, message, {'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'})
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysolr.py", line 394, in _send_request
     raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message))
 SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: ERROR: [doc=auth.user.23] unknown field 'firstname']
```

Also if somebody can point me in the right direction about how to implement Autocomplete for multiple fields. Like in this case for 'first_name', 'last_name' and 'email', how can I do that?

**Solution - Restarting Solr**

```
Stop Solr:   ./solr-4.10.4/bin/solr stop -all
Start Solr:  ./solr-4.10.4/bin/solr start -p 8983
```

Comment: Did you restart solr after changing the schema? It will not load the new schema until then.

Comment: Awesome!!! This worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @UtkarshSinha Can you please paste the command to restart solr?

Comment: Just added the stop and start commands to the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add documents to Solr 9, add them using the lines below...

```
import pysolr
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/core/', always_commit=True)
docs = {"id":3,"title": "Solr"} #This is what Solr LIKES. Solr will through an error if your do nested dictionary like this {"id":3,"title": "Solr", "_links": {"self": {"href": "/api/entries/7"}}}
solr.add(doc,commit=True)
```

The error I was getting in my case when I did nested dictionary is `SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: Error:[doc=3]  Unknown operation for the an atomic update: self]`